# Adjusting MKMapView's Frame on iOS 6 in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mkmapview

I'm trying to adjust the frame of my MKMapView created on IB for 4-inch devices but it doesn't work. Here's my code on viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // Resizing UILabel for 4-inch screen
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) // 4 inch
    {
        mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 504);
    }
    else // 3.5 inch
    {
        mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 416);
    }
    // END - Resizing UILabel for 4-inch screen
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this setup? Thanks.

Comment: can you tell us what is wrong? what part of it doesnt work?

Comment: My mapView doesn't resize to fit for 4 inch screens.

Comment: if you want the mapview to fill the view you should do it either with autoresizing masks (set these to the same as the view) or with autolayout (if you are targetting iOS 6 only)

Comment: How do you do it using autoresizing masks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to set the mapView to be the same size as the view controllers view (i.e. fill the screen), set the map view's frame to be the bounds of the view, and give them the same autoresizing masks (you can do this in viewDidLoad and you shouldn't have to test for screen size)

```
mapView.frame = self.view.bounds;
mapView.autoresizingMask = self.view.autoresizingMask;
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed the screen size condition.

Comment: btw, that if statement seemed fine to me in a quick test, so i think it was just the value of the frame you were setting that was the problem. but for filling the view you're better off without the if

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a static table View
One cell included a MapView.

Different iphone Screen Size : Different cell height for the map view cell.

I looked at different approach like :

```
mapView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

Unfortunately for me , it only works when user re-orientate the mobile => redraw?

My solution was to correctly use the AUTO LAYOUT in IB and use contraint 
And it solved my issue

```
Left Horizontal Space Constraint = '0'
Right Horizontal Space Constraint = '0'
Top Vertical Space Constraint = '0'
Bottom Vertical Space Constraint = '0'
```

--> this is my first post in stackoverflow.com !  :-)